# Can Jenkins/Hudson or Artifactory check all maven projects for the absence of a specific maven plugin in any pom.xml?

Tags: maven, jenkins, artifactory

My maven expert is helping us to make the most of maven in our project. One of his recent reccomendations was to make sure our projects use the maven-source-plugin so that anything we write puts its source in our repo.

The team is on board with this idea but we have many projects. We would like to find out which ones do not have this set and make sure that any new projects or modules have it set.

Can we use either:

- our continuous integration server (Jenkins) to enforce this as a code standard? Perhaps one of these plugins? https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Static+Code+Analysis+Plug-ins
- our repo (powered by JFrog Artifactory) to search for modules which DO NOT use this plugin?
- is there a search or dependency analysis tool that could help us?
- some other option we haven't considered?

We did think about an SVN pre-commit hook but rejected that. It would only be able to warn us about this when we commit a pom.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve it with [Artifactory user plugin.](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/User+Plugins)
You need an execution plugin that will:

- Find all the poms
- Iterate on them
- Get the content
- Search in text for the needed plugin
- Append to some report (text file or just to the log).

Then you call this plugin via REST (with cURL, for example).